# Golang getting a 404 whilst server is running

Tags: http, go, gorilla, mux

I am trying to run a basic web app, following a tutorial, using Golang and the routing package Gorilla/mux. The server is running fine but it refuses to find the index.html file regardless of what I put in the browser, always returning a 404.

Here is the code:

main.go

```
    package main

    import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    )

    const (
    host     = "localhost"
    port     = 5432
    user     = "postgres"
    password = "0102"
    dbname   = "bird_encyclopaedia"
)

func newRouter() *mux.Router {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/hello", handler).Methods("GET")


    staticFileDirectory := http.Dir("./assets/")
    staticFileHandler := http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(staticFileDirectory))
    r.PathPrefix("/assets/").Handler(staticFileHandler).Methods("GET")

    r.HandleFunc("/bird", getBirdHandler).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/bird", createBirdHandler).Methods("POST")
    return r
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting server dickface...")
    connString := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        host, port, user, password, dbname)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connString)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = db.Ping()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    InitStore(&dbStore{db: db})

    r := newRouter()
    fmt.Println("Serving on port 8080")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World!")
}
```

The html file is just in the assets/index.html directory, I can supply that if need be but I can't see the problem being in the actual html?

I have trawled through the code many times and cannot see why the server would not be able to find the directory. I have tried localhost/8080/assets, localhost/8080/assets/index.html, localhost/8080, and all other variants.

If I append it with /hello mind it returns the Hello world as seen in main.go
And if I append it with /bird it returns "null" instead of 404.

Comment: "localhost/8080" is not valid. Try "localhost:8080/

Comment: Sorry I meant localhost:8080 instead of localhost/8080

Comment: Please come up with a _minimal_ example.

Comment: Please explain @Volker

Comment: You posted several hundred lines of code, most which probably has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Ah I see. I apologise I just didn't want to omit anything that may have been useful seeing as I didn't know what the problem was myself. @Volker

Answer (score 1):

You don't need [http.StripPrefix()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix) since you are not using the `assets` in the URL.

---

Just change these two lines:

```
staticFileHandler := http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(staticFileDirectory))
r.PathPrefix("/assets/").Handler(staticFileHandler).Methods("GET")
```

to

```
staticFileHandler := http.FileServer(staticFileDirectory)
r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(staticFileHandler).Methods("GET")
```

Comment: Are you sure `./assets/` is in the working directory where you run your `main.go`?

Comment: Yes I'm 100% sure

Comment: Try this [snippet](https://pastebin.com/NGRw4YGt). Make sure to have `assets/index.html` in the same directory you run the binary. Access it via `http://localhost:8080/index.html`. This works very well for me.

Comment: Thank you Abdullah. None of this seems to be working for me. I severely suspect that it is something else that I am doing and not the actual routing code itself. Once I find a solution I will post it on here